# jib authentication not working when use docker

Tags: docker, jib

I logged in to docker normally, and the authentication information was also checked, but the jib build fails.

```
docker login
cat ~/.docker/config.json

{
    "auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}
    },
    "credsStore": "desktop"
}%
```

Docker login is successful.

```
// build.gradle

    jib {
        from {
            image = "eclipse-temurin:17"
        }

        to {
            image = "username/${project.name}:${project.version}"
            tags = ["latest"]
        }
    }
```

and command `./gradlew jib`

error message

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':jib-test:jib'.
> com.google.cloud.tools.jib.plugins.common.BuildStepsExecutionException: Build image failed, perhaps you should make sure your credentials for 'registry-1.docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin' are set up correctly. See https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/docs/faq.md#what-should-i-do-when-the-registry-responds-with-unauthorized for help
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a duplicate of these:

- [How to setup Jib container to authenticate with docker remote registry to pull images?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72365455/1701388)
- [401 Unauthorized when using jib to create docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72394364/1701388)
- https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/issues/3677

Try emptying `config.json` entirely or just delete the file. Particularly, remove the entry for `"https://index.docker.io/v1/"` and `credsStore`.